# get data from four tables using one signle query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables. First let me share their structure

**Sub category**

```
id
name
```

**Sub Category three**

```
id
name
sub_category_id
```

**products**

```
id
name
sub_category_three_id
```

**images**

```
 id
 image
 product_id
```

Now I want to get 1 sub_category, and on the base of sub_category(id) get all data from sub category three, and on the base of sub_category_three all the products of sub_category_three, and all the images on the base of products.

I tried this query on three tables but then it gets complicated so I came here.

```
SELECT sct.sct_name,sc_name,p.name 
  FROM sub_categories_three sct 
 INNER JOIN sub_categories sc 
    ON sc.id = sct.sub_category_id 
 INNER JOIN products p 
    ON sct.id = p.sub_category_three
```

Comment: The `images` table's  `product` column is a `foreign key` for the `name` or the `id` of the `products` table ?

Comment: try with left or right joins.

Comment: @ths yes, let me edit my question

Comment: Since there can be multiple images per product - How should the result look like? Do you want one row per image (duplicating the products) or one row per product (summerizing the images)?

Comment: one image against one product

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following query, it contains some explanations :

```
SELECT
    -- used aliases as most of the tables have same field names.
    -- not required but it will help us distinguish between the returned values.
    -- also the query will work without aliases as we did make aliases for table names which is required to prevent ambiguous field names. 
    `sc`.`id` AS `scID`,
    `sc`.`name` AS `scName`,
    `sct`.`id` AS `sctID`,
    `sct`.`name` AS `sctName`,
    `sct`.`sub_category_id`,
    `p`.`id` AS `pID`,
    `p`.`name` AS `pName`,
    `p`.`sub_category_three_id`,
    `i`.`id` AS `iID`,
    `i`.`image`,
    `i`.`product_id`
FROM `sub_categories` `sc`
INNER JOIN `sub_categories_three` `sct` ON -- link `sub_categories` and `sub_categories_three` tables 
    `sct`.`sub_category_id` = `sc`.`id` -- based on `sub_categories`.`id` and `sub_categories_three`.`sub_category_id`.
INNER JOIN `products` `p` ON -- link `sub_categories_three` and `products` tables
    `p`.`sub_category_three_id` = `sct`.`id` -- based on `sub_categories_three`.`id` and `products`.`sub_category_three_id`.
INNER JOIN `images` `i` ON -- link `products` and `images` tables
    `i`.`product_id` = `p`.`id` -- based on `products`.`id` and `images`.`product_id`.
WHERE `sc`.`id` = 1 -- a WHERE clause is needed, for demo purpuses I fetched only the row having `id` = 1 from `sub_categories` table. Change it per your requirements.
```

Hope that helps, feel free to ask for more clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple join query, to connect all tables:

```
select * from sub_category sc inner join
  sub_category_three sct on sc.id = sct.sub_category_id inner join
  products p on sct.id = p.sub_category_three_id inner join 
  images i on i.product_id = p.id
  where ....
```

Comment: please explain it a little bit.

Comment: it's preety straight forward- if table A has b_id column that matches the id column of B, you do `inner join on a.b_id = b.id` to connect them. if you need to join 4 tables, you do it three times.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple inner join query

```
SELECT * FROM products 
INNER JOIN images ON images.product_id = products.id                           //link images with product id 
INNER JOIN sub category three sct ON sct.id = products.subcategory_three_id    //link product subcategory three id with sub category three 
INNER JOIN sub category sc ON sc.id = sct.sub_category_id                     //finally link sub category with subcategory three `
```

Add Where condition if neccessary

**EDIT**

```
SELECT * FROM products 
INNER JOIN images ON images.product_id = products.id                           //link images with product id 
INNER JOIN sub category three sct ON sct.id = products.subcategory_three_id    //link product subcategory three id with sub category three 
INNER JOIN sub category sc ON sc.id = 
  (  SELECT id
       FROM sub category AS sc
        WHERE sc.id = sct.sub_category_id
        LIMIT 1

   )             //finally link sub category with subcategory three `
```

Comment: what if i only need one Sub_category name

Comment: i use your first query and it is return only name of products => `SELECT p.name,i.image,sc.sc_name,sct.sct_name FROM products p
INNER JOIN images i ON i.product_id = p.id                          
INNER JOIN sub_categories_three sct ON sct.id = p.sub_category_three
INNER JOIN sub_categories sc ON sc.id = sct.sub_category_id
where sc.id=1`

Comment: yea it will return the product with images with subcategory if not check the data
i think your 2nd inner join is wrong use p.sub_category_three_id @AliRaza